# Unexpected token < Error not going

Tags: reactjs

Its been 3 hours banging my head , but still i cant find what the error is , I am getting an error "Stack trace: SyntaxError: Unexpected token <". I have nearly tried all sort of solutions from stack overflow itself but nothing seems to work . So Plz help me out.

```
var argv = require('yargs')
    .option('p', {
        alias: 'port',
        description: 'Specify the server\'s port',
        default: 9009
    })
    .option('a', {
        alias: 'address',
        description: 'Specify the server\'s address',
        default: '127.0.0.1'
    })
    .help('h').alias('h', 'help')
    .strict()
    .argv;

var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var reactRender = require('react-render');

// Ensure support for loading files that contain ES6+7 & JSX
require('babel-core/register')({
    presets:["es2015","react"]
   });

var ADDRESS = argv.address;
var PORT = argv.port;

var app = express();
var server = http.Server(app);

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.end('React render server');
});

app.post('/render', function(req, res) {
    reactRender(req.body, function(err, markup) {
        if (err) {
            res.json({
                error: {
                    type: err.constructor.name,
                    message: err.message,
                    stack: err.stack
                 },
                markup: null
             });
        } else {
           res.json({
                error: null,
                markup: markup
            });
        }
    });
});

server.listen(PORT, ADDRESS, function() {
    console.log('React render server listening at http://' + ADDRESS +    ':' + PORT);
});
```

I am using browserify with React. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: unexpected token, In which line?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your ajax call is returning HTML instead of JSON (perhaps because you're getting an error page) so your `res.json` is seeing the beginning of the page as `<html>...` and erroring. Try logging the response and looking at it to make sure it's legit JSON.